# Finding Public IP of router on different LAN

Tags: router, wireless-router, kali-linux, scanning

Is there any possible way to acquire a public IP of a network without joining it's network?

Let's say Router A is on LAN A, 
I'm connected to LAN B, and I want to access the login page of Router A without being connected to LAN A

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi Aldiandya, welcome on Super User. Please take some moments to read the page [ask]. What have you tried and where are your difficulties? Btw usually routers are configured to have the page that allows to modify the settings, accessible only from a wired connection from the "internal" network, for security reasons... In few cases that page can be accessed only from a single specific (physical) port. Feel you free to [edit] your question adding some other details.

Comment: How are Router A and Router B connected?

Answer (score 0):

First, for acquiring a public IP address of a network, you can open up terminal and type `ping <website name>` to ping the website server, and it will show up something like this:
`PING www.google.com (216.58.194.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dfw06s48-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.194.100): icmp_req=1 ttl=53 time=25.1 ms`
The IP after the `PING www.google.com` is the public IP of the website.
 As for viewing a page of a different server without actually being on it, there are a few ways. First is using the cached version (which is a saved copy of the website a computer can store) and you can also use a website mirror, which looks and can function exactly like the original website. The bad thing about website mirrors when they aren't owned by the same company are that they are often phishing scams. It's often just best to go to "LAN A" for viewing the page.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. I would be surprised if there was a public website hosted on a router and even more surprised if the login page was cached anywhere.

Comment: The 216.58.194.100 is just the IP for google's server. Honestly, I'm not too sure what pages are and aren't cached, but google's wayback machine has a ton of cached pages. In addition, sometimes when you visit a webpage a lot, even if your computer isn't connected to the internet, it's able to display a cached version of the page that you visit so often. Geolocation of google's server: https://ipinfo.io/216.58.194.100

Comment: @Unnameduser: each of these sites can cache only the pages that are accessible to the robot, seldom even the ones that should be excluded (it is not legal but it is not this the point). _Probably_  the OP is asking how to access to a router of another LAN when you are not physically connected to that LAN. Look at the tag excerpt of `kali-linux` to have an idea about the aim. `;-)`. Now if my guess is right, the OP refers to the login page that allow to modify the router settings, that is not accessible from outside the LAN in a _normal_ way... That page cannot be cached from google et al..